How do I fix a stuck deadbolt where the screws are obstructed?
The deadbolt in the picture is stuck in the locked position. There is some play in the deadbolt so it does not appear to be the case that the door is sagging or the plate is misaligned. I suspect something is broken in the internals. The problem is I cannot access the screw to remove the lock. It is obstructed by the thumb turn. Any suggestions?


It is highly unusual for a deadbolt to malfunction internally. The usual issue is pressure on the bolt in the hole. Have you tried to pushin, pullout, pull up on the door as you turned the deadbolt handle?

I think Triplefault's destructive method might be required here.
But before you do that, have you tried taking out the exposed screw?
I'd first try taking out the screw that you can access, and see if it gives the lock any more play.  With one screw out it might be loose enough that you can move things around a bit to expose the second screw enough to unscrew it.

Also add in @RMDman's comment.

This looks like "pretend to be a burglar" time: destroy the lock. Get a big  channel lock or vise grip or pipe wrench and crank on the handle until it either breaks loose or off. Then you can unscrew the plate.
Remove the guts and replace with a new deadbolt.
